# Ant 1.8.1 and StarTeam

Tags: ant, starteam

I'm using Ant 1.8.1 and StarTeam 2008 R2.

I noticed in previous versions of Ant there were optional tasks which could be used to access a StarTeam repository.

These tasks seem to be absent in Ant 1.8.1?  What happened to them?  Do any tasks exist to do this, or do you have to create your own tasks using the StarTeam SDK 10.4 (which looks straightforward enough, but I wouldn't want to duplicate an existing effort)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tasks are present in the `ant-starteam.jar`.

I've noticed my binary distributions of ant 1.6 and 1.7 has this jar in the lib directory. But 1.8 does not.

This URL http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/starteam/package-index.html still defines these classes as part of the javadoc API for ant 1.8, so I guess it should work if you add the ant-starteam.jar into the ant/lib directory

Comment: I've actually been looking at the source for these tasks, found here: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Build/ANT/org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.starteam.htm  They seem to work fine.  I don't understand why these were excluded from Ant in version 1.8.1, and I can't find a 1.8.1 version of ant-starteam.jar anywhere.  It just vanished!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ant 1.8.2 on OS X and was able to use the ant-starteam.jar for 1.7.1.  Had to pass the location of the starteam library to ant like so

```
ant -lib "/Applications/starteam-en-10.4.7-java/lib/"
```

Saw this pointer on another forum.  T